# Defining a function that behaves differently according to whether the argument is Integral or Fractional

Tags: haskell, ghc

A sort-of solution is to write out a bunch of instances by hand,

```
class Halve a where
  halve :: a -> a

instance Halve Int where
  halve = (`div` 2)
instance Halve Integer where
  halve = (`div` 2)
instance Halve Float where
  halve = (/ 2)
instance Halve Double where
  halve = (/ 2)
-- ... etc.
```

However some instances will inevitably be missed, such as user-defined ones. My attempted real solution is this non-working code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Halve a where
  halve :: a -> a

instance Integral a => Halve a where
  halve = (`div` 2)
instance Fractional a => Halve a where
  halve = (/ 2)
```

which gives the error

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
  instance Integral a => Halve a
    -- Defined at ...
  instance Fractional a => Halve a
    -- Defined at ...
```

I haven't found how to express this correctly, if it can be done.

Comment: Sounds like you're not really interested in halving numbers, but in _obtaining pivot values between two elements_? That's quite reaonable. I think you should keep it completely seperate from these numerical classes then (because this might also make sense for e.g. characters).

Comment: Would it hurt too much to tell us what your actual ultimate objective is? We might well be able to help you more effectively if we knew what you were *really* trying to do.

Comment: Type constraints are not enough to decide the instances. What if someone defines a type with instances of both Integral and Fractional? You need distinctive type constructors, like @daniel-wagner suggested below

Answer (score 4):

You can't:

```
data Hell = YouCantDoThat

instance Integral Hell

instance Fractional Hell
```

There is no rule saying that an `Integral` cannot be a `Fractional` or viceversa. And if that's the case how do you choose?
This is exactly what the error is telling you.

Comment: @CNJ Yes, but in this case you actually want to use the conflict in the ambiguity. If you remove all references of `Integral` and `Fractional` from your code you don't get any error using the `Hell` datatype, which is equivalent to what you are saying about imports and conflicting names. Problem is: you are back to using the boilerplate code.

Comment: @CNJ, once you throw in multi-parameter type classes, functional dependencies, flexible contexts, flexible instances, undecidable instances, and equality constraints (all of which are essential to modern Haskell programming), Haskell's class system pretty much reaches the limit of programmers' ability to use and reason about. There's a limit to how complex a system can get before it stops being useful.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is pretty much horrible. What is the *meaning* of this class? It's also impossible to do it with significantly less boilerplate than your working partial solution. The problem is that GHC, even with overlapping or incoherent (*barf*) instances will always commit to an instance based on the part of the instance head to the right of the `=>`.

GHC *never* acts on the belief that a type is *not* an instance of a class except to produce an error message.

Comment: @CNJ, either that way or outside the class system altogether.

Comment: @CNJ, no, it's not. But I have the feeling you might be able to restructure your code to push this distinction to a higher level (the one that leads to the invariant that integral arguments will be even, perhaps). As it is, this just doesn't *feel* like an appropriate use for a class. Haskell classes should really represent specific, well-behaved *ideas*, not just convenient overloading.

Answer (score 2):

Try making the function to halve a value be a specific input to your code.

```
foobar :: (Ord x) => (x -> x) -> x -> x -> ...
foobar halve x1 x2 = ...
```

It's kind of annoying, but hopefully you only have to specify this once, at the very top of your algorithm. Any child functions can just receive the parameter passed on.

Another alternative would be to do something like

```
data Halvable x = Halvable {value :: x, halve :: x -> y}

halfInt :: Integral x => x -> Halvable x
halfInt x = Halvable x (`div` 2)

halfFrac :: Fractional x => x -> Halvable x
halfFrac x = Halvable x (/ 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

One lightweight way would be to define two new types, thus:

```
newtype FracWrap a = F a deriving Fractional
newtype IntWrap  a = I a deriving Integral

instance Fractional a => Halve (FracWrap a) where halve = (/2)
instance Integral   a => Halve (IntWrap  a) where halve = (`div`2)
```

Then, for `foo` which takes a `Halve`-constrained argument, one has the relatively lightweight `foo.F` and `foo.I` to indicate whether one wants to use the `Fractional` or `Integral` version of `foo`.

This is relatively nice in terms of API design, as the API designer need not offer two version of everything; just one `Halve`-specific version of everything, and two adapters.